# Photoshop eyedropper sets background colour, not foreground

Tags: photoshop

I've been putting up with this for probably too long. For some odd reason, when I used the Photoshop CS5 eyedropper tool, it sets the background colour - which is really annoying.  I've never experienced this in all my years of using Photoshop.  Each time I set a colour, I'm forced to then use the x keyboard shortcut to swap the background/foreground colours.

How do you get the eyedropper tool back to the default setting? (without re-installing :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Wow - ok it was easy.  Go to Window > Color, then ensure the foreground colour is the selected one.  There's a really fine, almost un-noticable line around the one that is selected.  Mine was set on the background colour.

Comment: OMG this has been driving me NUTS thanks! First time I've ever experienced this in Photoshop, been putting up with it forever...

Comment: Helped me in 2017 :)

Comment: August 2018. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also click on the one you want to set, in the toolbar, then pick the colour. That's what I usually do anyways I think!

Comment: Thanks, that is the manual way of doing it, but that doesn't solve the issue of using the eyedropper by pressing the keybard shortcut of "i", which is the fastest way of choosing a colour from your desisgn